# Converting array to JSON object array

Tags: json, laravel, foreach

I am facing problem getting the JSON object array from the following code.

```
public function staffStatusFromSameDept($deptID)
{
    $sameDeptEmployee=StaffsModel::where("DepartmentID","=",$deptID)->get();
    $count=$sameDeptEmployee->count();
    if ($count>0) 
    {
        foreach ($sameDeptEmployee as  $value) 
        {
            $data=DB::table('status')
                 ->join('staffs','status.StaffPin', '=', 'staffs.StaffPin')
                 ->select('staffs.StaffName','staffs.DesignationName',
                          'status.staffStatus', 'status.currentLocation',
                          'staffs.EmailID','staffs.MobileNO','status.returnTime','staffs.Photo' )
                 ->where('staffs.StaffPin','=',$value->StaffPin)
                 ->get();

            $response[]=$data;
        }
    }
    else{
        $response=["error" => "Invalid Department ID"];
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Actual output:

> [[{"StaffName":"Mamun hosen","DesignationName":"PO(MF)","staffStatus":"working","currentLocation":"rangpur","EmailID":"mamun@brac.net","MobileNO":"01716340278","returnTime":"04:30","Photo":"helal.jpg"}],[{"StaffName":"nahid
>   hasan","DesignationName":"PO(MF)","staffStatus":"working","currentLocation":"rangpur","EmailID":"nahid@brac.net","MobileNO":"01716340278","returnTime":"04:30","Photo":"helal.jpg"}]]

Expected output:

> [{"StaffName":"Mamun hosen","DesignationName":"PO(MF)","staffStatus":"working","currentLocation":"rangpur","EmailID":"mamun@brac.net","MobileNO":"01716340278","returnTime":"04:30","Photo":"helal.jpg"},{"StaffName":"nahid
>   hasan","DesignationName":"PO(MF)","staffStatus":"working","currentLocation":"rangpur","EmailID":"nahid@brac.net","MobileNO":"01716340278","returnTime":"04:30","Photo":"helal.jpg"}]

The problem in my code is that each person details taking JSON object array. But I want one JSON object array and each of the person's details I will get from this JSON object array.

Answer (score 0):

Because `->get()` will return an array of records found.

So if your query always has 1 record, change `->get()` to `->first()`, otherwise use `$response  = array_merge($response, $data)` instead of `$response[] = $data`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the `$response[]=$data;` to `$response=$data;`